# Listbox reversed items order

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

I've spend couple of hours trying to reverse the order of listbox (bottom to top) as described on the picture:
[image]

That means that newly added items should be inserted at the top of the listbox. I do not understand that something so trivial can be so difficult to implement in wpf...

I do not want to use transient effects on panel and items itself because it causes strange behavior on scrollviewer. I can not use some sort definitions on ICollectionView because I want to use a **data** virtualization which provides ordered data and I have to add them as is.

This is my Listbox (ListView) definition:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
              VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
              VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" 
              ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"> <!--To manage scrolling from view model using ICollectionView.ScrollTo()-->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate> 
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <!--To auto scroll to bottom (via calling ICollectionView.ScrollToBottom()-->
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:ScrollIntoCurrentItemBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <!--To pin listbox panel to bottom-->
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

Is there any acceptable solution for that? I really appreciate any help! thanks

Comment: Data virtualization and using collection view sorting should not be in conflict, i thing.

Comment: In my case yes, it causes to read all data for sorting purpose. But it is a another story which is not a subject of question.

Comment: Bind to a `ReversedCollection` property in your view model. Instead of `Collection.Add(item)` call `ReversedCollection.Insert(0, item)`.

Comment: I cannot call Insert instead of Add because I use special type of collection VirtualizedObservableCollection which support data virtualization and has to be strictly binded to ListView.
To simplify, I have to change ListView behavior instead of the underlying source (collection).